# c# Codedom write Program Settings to Generated File

Tags: c#, settings

I would ask if its Possible to use Settings with `Codedom` [like this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Example:
Write settings to Fresh Generated `Executable` file ,like `Resources` or something smiliar.

I have searched on  msdn but didnt find something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not directly with CodeDom. As its name suggests, **Code** Dom is about, well, code, and what you can do with it. You can in theory generate an assembly via CodeDom, and then manipulate it using other libraries to embed the resources on it.

Comment: Hmm no you can directly add a resource in the compiled file like :CompilerParameters options = new CompilerParameters();                                                  options.EmbeddedResources.Add(resourcefile);